dummy dml after with's in plpgsql
Sometimes it is useful to use dml in with-blocks, e.g.
with 
  common_data_for_ins_and_upd as (
    select ...
  ),
  ins as (
     insert into some_table(...)
  ),
  upd as (
     update some_table set ...
  )
select

This works fine in sql, but trying to use this construct in plpgsql gives ERROR: query has no destination for result data.
Trying to replace select with perform gives syntax error at or near "perform".
Trying to frame it all in an outer perform gives WITH clause containing a data-modifying statement must be at the top level.
Of course, I could take the last dml-with block out of the with
with 
  ins as (
     insert into some_table(...)
  )
update some_table set ...

or write something like delete from some_table where false,
but maybe there is some more elegant solution?
upd. the select into construct works, but requires declaring a garbage variable.

That error query has no destination for result data is not from dml used in a CTE. You did not post the entire statement but the select does not contain the into  clause. That clause is required in plpgsql.  If this is not the issue then post the entire query instead of just ....

Of course, this is not from dml. it is from final 'select'.
I can declare additional variable and use select into but this variable is garbage (

According to the error message, you just have to assign to a variable the returning result of select statement (since it always has a returning value, at least NULL), like this
do $$
declare res varchar;
begin
    with 
      ins as (
         insert into some_table(...)
      ),
      upd as (
         update some_table set ...
      )
    select into res;
    raise notice 'Returning value from select statement %', res;
end $$;

Other option, discarding the result from select statement (and avoid using a variable)
do $$
begin
    execute
    'with 
      ins as (
         insert into some_table(...)
      ),
      upd as (
         update some_table set ...
      )
    select';
    perform 1;  
end $$;

And using variables for query parameters
do $$
declare 
    value1 varchar;
    value2 varchar;
    value3 float;
begin
    execute (
    'with 
      ins as (
         insert into some_table values($1, $2, $3)
      ),
      upd as (
         update some_table set ...
      )
    select') using value1, value2, value3;
    perform 1;  
end $$;


Yes, It works,  but maybe there is some solution without additional trash variable.

Executing a select without into clause is not allowed, however those instructions don't need a WITH in PL/pgSQL simply you have to do do $$ begin  insert into some_table(...);   update some_table set ...;  end $$; without "trash" variable.

Correct, but insert and update as separate plpgsql statements cannot use shared with statements. Maybe my first example is oversimplified )
Added common clause.

With perform is possible to discard the select statement result, added an example of use.

Oh, It seems to work even without the perform, thank you.
The only drawback, perhaps, is that the text going under execute is not checked for correct syntax before execution and cannot use variables declared in plpgsql code.

Yes its checked and also you can use variables for parameters, look at dynamic statements https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN.
